# WPF DataGridRow.IsNewItem Remained True even after DataGridRow.Item its NOT CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

After tracking the `DataGridRow.Item` and `DataGridRow.IsNewItem` properties, I discover that: each added item (to DataGrid when Source is `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`), 
`IsNewItem` Always positive, Although `Item` Although he is not a `NewItemPlaceholder`.

Afterwards I looked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.isnewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and saw that it was indeed affected by two factors:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the DataGridRow is a placeholder for a new item **or for an item that has not been committed**.

How do I **committ** added item?

Comment: Isn't Check for `Item is NewItemPlaceHolder` sufficient?

Comment: sufficient, but not from XAML...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison against `NewItemPlaceholder` purely in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                 Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
        <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```